# Java basic compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a simple error in a very simple start of a program that has me stumped.  I've included comments of the errors on the appropriate lines.  What am I missing?  (Yes, I am a nube.)

```
package mainPack;

public class Bodies{

    int mass;
    int radius;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    float xvel;
    float yvel;   //Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

    public Bodies(mass, radius, xpos, ypos, xvel, yvel){
    }

}   //Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Comment: By the way, welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that the parameters in your constructor have no data types.

**NB:**
  Since your parameter names are the same as your instance variable names, you will need to use `this`, as in:

```
   public Bodies(int mass, int radius, int xpos, int ypos, float xvel, float yvel)
    {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
        //...
    }
```

where `this.mass` refers to the instance variable `mass`, as opposed to the passed parameter of the constructor.

For more information, check out the [Oracle Tutorial on Java Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

**As an aside, on `float` also from Oracle**:

> As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead
>   of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating
>   point numbers. This data type should never be used for precise values,
>   such as currency.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring the constructor, you need to specify the types of its arguments:

```
public Bodies(int mass, int radius, int xpos, int ypos, float xvel, float yvel) {
```

Having done this, you also need to initialize the data members:

```
public Bodies(int mass, int radius, int xpos, int ypos, float xvel, float yvel) {
   this.mass = mass;
   ...
```

Comment: The `this` keyword refers to the current object. In this case, it is `Bodies`. Just thought I'd add this comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the types of the parameters as well as their names in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
package mainPack;

public class Bodies{

    int mass;
    int radius;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    float xvel;
    float yvel;

    public Bodies(int mass, int radius, int xpos, int ypos, float xvel, float yvel){
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.xvel = xvel;
        this.yvel = yvel;
    }

}
```

You were missing the types for the arguments for the constructor. You will probably want to initialize the fields in the constructor, so I did it also.